# Read non-finalized CD in OS X

Tags: macos, iso-image, compact-disc

I occasionally get an Audio CD from our weekly recordings that hasn't been finalized (someone forgot before ejecting the disk from our standalone CD recorder).

Under Windows, this wasn't too much of a hassle. IsoBuster could read it and extract the audio track data despite the fact that it was not finalized.

What I'd like is that functionality but under OS X.

Any ideas if this is doable...? I can `dd` the disk but I'm not sure what I'm getting and how I'd have to format/convert this data to make it readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe dd is capable of bypassing the driver, which is what you'd need to do in order to copy anything off of a broken filesystem. One of the data recovery apps out there might be able to help you, but I have no idea if any of them support Redbook audio CDs.

Comment: I resorted to my dusty copy of Windows XP with IsoBuster. There's probably some comparable OS X (non-free) utilities but I didn't want to shell out anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at it with Disk Utility? It might be able to mount the partition, or close the disc.

Comment: It says that it can't be initialized when the disc is first inserted. It does not mount under Disk Utility and I can't see any options to close out or finalize through Disk Utility.

Comment: What if you use a disc burning software like Toast? (get a trial to test)

Answer (score 0):

cmd-opt-i is supposed to force mount ISO-9660 partitions of a CD when it first spins up. Or just opt is supposed to show each session on a CD.

What kind of burner? Alesis?

Comment: An audio CD generally has no partitions, ISO-9660 or otherwise.